# Split file into X amount of even sized files?

Tags: linux

I have found multiple ways to split files into X amount of lines or X size but I was wondering how do I split a file into 5 evenly sized files for example?

This will be for .csv file if that matters.

Comment: "Evenly sized"?  For a CSV file, this would mean truncating lines in the file.  Do you "equal number of lines" instead?

Comment: In general, one record in a CSV file may span multiple lines (if it has quoted text, for example). So even breaking the file based on the number of lines could potentially leave you with partial records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look at `wc -l` and `split`. Putting them together you get:

```
split -l $(($(wc -l <myfile.txt)/5)) myfile.txt
```

That will split `myfile.txt` into 5 even sized files (assuming myfile lines are divisible by 5). default output to `xaa`, `xab` .... You can set the suffixes with the `-a`, `-d` and `--additional-suffix=suffix` options.

Another method of splitting is into `chunks` which will provide even line number of chunks until the last file and dump any excess (non-divisible by 5) lines there.

```
split -n 5 myfile.txt
```

You can use the `-b` option to split into an even number of **bytes**, but that doesn't sound good for a `.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a files into files of N lines with:

```
split -l [number of lines] inputfile
```

So you just need to compute the numbers of lines to obtain 5 files:

```
ln=$(wc -l < inputfile)
split -l $((ln / 5 + (ln % 5 > 0))) inputfile
```